# In Dash Plotly, what is the difference between graph, chart, plot and figure?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I know that in linguistics these terms can be used interchangeably, but are there specific definitions in Dash Plotly, or, generally, in data science?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty interchangeable. A figure is used as a blanket term to describe a graphic representation. Nearly every peer reviewed publication refers to graphics as figure, followed by numeric identifier.

The official terms have been detailed as:

A graph is a diagram of a mathematical function, but can also be used (loosely) about a diagram of statistical data.

A chart is a graphic representation of data, where a line chart is one form.

A plot is the result of plotting statistics as a diagram in different ways, where some of the ways are similar to some chart types.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43027/whats-the-difference-between-a-graph-a-chart-and-a-plot

But past that it comes down to specific cases; scatter plot, bar graph, line chart, pie chart.

And as for plotly, it purely depends on how they wrote their documentation/api. For example if you wanted to make a line graph/chart/plot/figure you'd

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='lines',
```

or a pie chart

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)])
fig.show()
```

As you can see plotly doesn't really refer to them as graph/chart/plot/figure its just defined as its intrinsic nature...that is a line or a pie or a scatter. More so their documentation uses the words chart/plot/figure/graph interchangeably.